# Single Form - Submitting value of a non clicked button when a separate input (submit type) is pressed?

Tags: jquery, html, forms

How do I submit the value of a button that the user has not pressed in a single form when the user presses another input type=submit?

I have tried to trigger the click of the button (not pressed), but it is only causing the triggered button value to submit.

Is there any way to submit two buttons even when one is pressed?

For example, if "input" is pressed then also press button (id="button").

```js
 $("input").click(function()
 {
        $("#button").trigger('click');
 });
```

EDIT: New function with submit ability but still not working as hoped.

```
$("input").click(function(e)
{
    e.preventDefault();
    e.stopPropagation();
    $("#button").trigger('click');
    $("#log_form").submit();
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to stop the propagation of the event that the clicked button is triggering.

So, the right code is this:

```
$("input").click(function(e)
 {
        e.preventDefault();
        e.stopPropagation();     
        $("#button").trigger('click');
 });
```

Comment: I can't seem to capture the $_POST of each element (input and #button) on the server.  Am I missing something more fundamental or is it not possible to get the $_POST of the two elements even when only one is physically pressed by the user.

Comment: Let me see if I'm getting it. So, you have two forms on the page and you want to send one precise form when clicking on the submit button of the other one? Right? Be careful that if you attach this click event on a generic $("input") element, this would prevent each form to be submitted using the <input type="submit" />.

Comment: I forgot the event (e) argument to my function as you included in the provided code.  Thanks.

Comment: Actually, I have a single form that I want both the input and button to submit when the user presses the input button.

Comment: Can you provide a sample fiddle?

Comment: Use an hidden input and store the value of the button inside it. This input will always be posted to the server.

Answer (score 0):

HTML with JavaScript would be cool... Here I'll provide you simple code (^_^) 
 
JavaScript: Insert in between head tags

```
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
// <![CDATA[

    function button_onclick() {
        window.navigate("page2.html");
    }

// ]]>
</script>
```

In between body tags, Insert this code

```
<input id="button" type="button" value="Page2" style="width:150px; height:30px;" onclick="button_onclick()" />
```